# Magento 2 - How to add data from a field in sales-order-item table to the order items in order confirmation email

Tags: magento2.4, sales-order, email-templates

I have a custom input field on each product item in the cart. The value is added to the sales-order-item table. The field is exposed to the order api as a custom attribute. I want to add the value of this field to each order item listed in the new order email that is sent to the customer. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the items.phtml code

Path:app/design/frontend/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

And you can add your custom attribute like below,

```
            <td class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getSku() ?>
            </td>
            <td class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
            </td>
            <td class="item-sku">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getPrice() ?>
            </td>
           <td class="item-custom-attribute">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getCustomAtrribute() ?>
            </td>
```

here is overrided file,

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems();
 ?>



<table class="email-items" style="width: 650px; text-align="left"">

        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 320px;  ">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 100px; ">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Sku') ?>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA;width: 100px; ">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:#EAEAEA; width: 120px;">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
            <td class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getName()?>
               <table class="item-info">

        <?php 
            $options = $_item->getProductOptions();           
            $s="";
            $d="";
                if (isset($options['options']) ) {        
                    foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
                        $s= $option['label'];
                        $d= $option['value'];
                    }
                }
        ?>

                   <tr class="item-price">
                       <td class="item-price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $s?></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr class="item-price">
                       <td class="item-price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $d?></td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getSku() ?>
            </td>
            <td class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
            </td>
            <td class="item-sku">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getPrice() ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?></table>
       <table align="right" style="border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 1em; width: 650px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?></td>
            <td align="right">  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getSubtotal() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Shipping & Handling') ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getShippingAmount() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Tax') ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getTaxAmount() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Grant total') ?></th>
            <th align="right"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_order->getGrandTotal() ?></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you - works well for me

Comment: Please accept it and upvote it, thanks:)